# how to get weekday and weekend count for months?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query where I need to count weekdays and weekends for following months

```
SELECT 
  fname, 
  MONTH(eventDate), 
  SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(eventDate) < 5,1,0)) AS WeekdayCount,
  SUM(IF(WEEKDAY(eventDate) >= 5,1,0)) AS WeekendCount
FROM eventcal AS e
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON e.primary = u.username
GROUP BY fname, MONTH(eventDate);
```

But I'm having a problem with timestamp and I'm getting this

```
(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42883 (undefined_function) function weekday(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
```

since I have an event date which is a timestamp for inserted_at. It's not able to do query on that. What should I do?

does postgres doesn't have this function?

what can be an alternative to this in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EXTRACT` with the date part `isodow`.  This returns a value of 1 to 7 for Monday through Sunday.

```sql
SELECT
    u.fname, 
    MONTH(e.eventDate),
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(idodow FROM e.eventDate) < 6) AS WeekdayCount,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(idodow FROM e.eventDate) IN (6, 7)) AS WeekendCount,
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN eventcal e ON e.primary = u.username
GROUP BY
    u.fname,
    MONTH(e.eventDate);
```

Note also that a left join from `users` to the `eventcal` table would seem to make the most sense here, not the reverse.

Comment: `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(idodow FROM e.eventDate) >= 6 AS WeekendCount`

for weekend we can also write this right?

Comment: @Max Yes, you could do it that way.  It is a matter of style and choice.